# Displaying the correct value on a Laravel blade upon date picker date change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my laravel application's blade I have a div to show total sales of a given day.

```
<div class="row mt-3" id="shopify_row1">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="shopify_widget1">
            <div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-white">
                <img class="img-fluid pull-left" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/social-media-2092/100/social-35-512.png" width="32" height="32">
                <h6 class="text-secondary mt-2 px-4">Shopify</h6>
                <hr class="border border-white">
                <h5 class="text-white">Total Orders</h5>
                <span class="tot_o" id="tot_o">{{ $tot_o }}</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I get this `$tot_o` via controller.

Now I'm trying to implement a date picker, so does the value of `$tot_o` should be changed according to the picked date, on change.

This is my date picker.

```
<td>
      <input id="date" class="date form-control" type="date">
</td>
```

And this is my JavaScript.

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/home',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){

            //$('#shopify_widget1').hide(); 
            console.log('rgfgfg');

            },
            timeout:10000
        });

    });    
    </script>
```

Following is in my controller's `index()`

```
//Total orders
            if($request->has('selected_date')){
                $selected_date=$request->selected_date;
                $url = "https://MYAPIKEY@MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_max=".$selected_date."";
            }else{
                $selected_date = date('Y-m-d');
                $url = "https://MYAPIKEY@MYSTORE.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/orders/count.json?status=any&created_at_min=".$selected_date."";
            }
            $curl = curl_init( $url );
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $result_1 = json_decode($json_response, TRUE);
            $tot_o = $result_1['count'];
```

but in my JavaScript, I'm struggling to complete this part... I want to clear existing `$tot_o` value and display the new value according to the selected date. Initially this is set to the current date value.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            url : '/home',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){

            //$('#shopify_widget1').hide(); 
            console.log('rgfgfg');

            },
            timeout:10000
        });
```

When I inspect my network tab, I can see my date is passing to controller correctly on every date change and it gives the correct `$tot_o` value as well in the response.

But it's not displaying on my blade's div...

My console.log also not printing....

***UPDATE***

As Sachin mentioned in the comments, I've removed the `datatype` and now I can print my `console.log`(this is not important.using this just to check my output.) and I can hide the previous value for `$tot_o`. My updated JS now looks like this..

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', '#date', function (e) {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url : '/home',
            data : {selected_date : $('#date').val()},
            success:function(data){

            $('#tot_o').empty(); 
            console.log('rgfgfg');

            },
            timeout:10000
        });

    });    
    </script>
```

But I'm yet to display the correct value on the blade...

Comment: Handle the error as well. Also, remove the `datatype` and then try.

Comment: if `console.log` output isn't seen in the console tab it means it doesn't reach the success block, might be better to check the network tab and see the anatomy of the ajax request what happened there.

Comment: @Kevin I have removed the datatype as mentioned by the sachin and now I'm getting the console log print